# Not able to connect to Snowflake hosted on AWS from my Azure Spring Apps application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-spring-cloud

I am encountering a connectivity issue while attempting to connect to Snowflake from my Azure Spring Apps application. The application fails to establish a connection, and the logs show the following exception stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: no further information
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='balxxxx.xxxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=s31d5e5a-62c8-4cfa-b97c-f78e6160f907&request_guid=1b427ccf-ed08-4184-ad2d-01c09d3ac441 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x135b87910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
> ...
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

I am using `snowflake-jdbc` version `3.14.4`

I am stuck and not sure what exactly needs to be done in order to resolve this issue. is it because I am trying to connect across cloud providers from Azure to AWS?

I tried connecting it from my local but still getting the above error. I verified the public private keys, but it didn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be quite clear. your app probably does not have connectivity to Snowflake db (assuming public/private key pair configuration is done correctly). I would suggest to review Network Configuration as following:

1. **IP Allowlisting:** Ensure the IP address of your Azure Spring Apps instance is allowed in Snowflake's network settings. [This post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000zuym3KAA/how-can-we-whitelist-an-aws-account-on-our-snowflake-account) and [this post](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies) might be helpful
2. **Firewall Rules:** Verify that firewall rules between Azure and Snowflake are configured correctly to allow inbound and outbound traffic on the necessary ports.
3. **Outbound Connectivity:** Check for any restrictions on outbound connectivity from your Azure Spring Apps instance.

Also, your error seems very similar to one posted here : https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Examples-of-Connectivity-Troubleshooting .try to follow the suggested steps and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so you mean that cross connectivity is allowed? I will go through above and will get back if further help required. thanks

Comment: yes, I guess it is allowed. I don't see any reason for not allowing connectivity between cloud providers

Comment: looks like the issue was The IPs for Spring app added to allow list for snowflake, had changed when I recreated the app on azure. After updating the allow-list, it started working without any issues. thanks for pointing me to above posts